# How to combine, remove duplicates, and sort two collections into third collection with linq

Tags: linq

Collection A:   3, 2, 1

Collection B:   3, 4

Resulting New Collection:  1, 2, 3 (from B, not A), 4

To make this more clear, here is the example with more details:

```
MyCustomClass[] list1 = { new MyCustomClass(3, "A"), new MyCustomClass(2, "B"), new MyCustomClass(1, "C") };


MyCustomClass[] list2 = { new MyCustomClass(3, "AA"), new MyCustomClass(5, "D") };
```

The list should return:
1C, 2B, 3AA, 5D

**Edit:**
 The trick here was implementing EqualityComparer<>, NOT IEqualityComparer<> as the latter is not used by Union.

```
var combined = list2.Union(list1, new MyEqualityComparer()).OrderBy(a=> a.Value);
```

Comment: What do you mean 'from B, not A' ? 3 is 3, it has no backstory.

Comment: The example is in int's for clarity. The actual sequence are objects which have a guid for a key, and a value.  If the guid is the same, I need the value from B, not A as they will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
var C = A.Union(B).OrderBy(i => i);
```

Comment: You're confusing IEnumerable and List methods. Union returns an IEnumerable<T>, which has no Sort extension method AFAIK. either call ToList before you Sort, or use OrderBy(i => i). Also List<T>.Sort() does not return anything - it's a void.

Comment: @JaceRhea Actually it seems Kirill is correct, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Union returns all, including duplicates.  So it returns 1,2,3,3,4. I need the item from the second list, if it is the same as an item from the first list.

Comment: Union does not return duplicates. It returns 1,2,3,4. The fact that two of your objects have the same guid does not make them equal, you will have to implement that logic yourself.